# How to use poisoning function of address sanitizer with ASAN_POISON_MEMORY_REGION macro (at clang++)?

Tags: clang, address-sanitizer

Now, I'm trying to use poisoning function of Address Sanitizer at clang++ compiler.
I thought I should use `ASAN_POISON_MEMORY_REGION` macro according to this description(https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerManualPoisoning).
And then, I wrote a brief program like below.

```
int main() {
    int* data = new int[10];

    // poisoning from data[5] to data[9]
    ASAN_POISON_MEMORY_REGION(data+5, sizeof(int)*5);

    for (int i=0; i<=5; ++i) {
        data[i] = i;
    }
}
```

But compiler says `error: use of undeclared identifier 'ASAN_POISON_MEMORY_REGION'` and not working.

Next, I add `#include <sanitizer/asan_interface.h>` as a header.
But It also doesn't worked correctly(with error `fatal error: 'sanitizer/asan_interface.h' file not found` ).

Do I have to do something setting? or include another header?

Comment: What is the compile command line you are using? What is the _exact_ error message?

Comment: Which clang version are you using?

Comment: @Employed Russian I used this compile command "clang++ -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer main.cpp".
And, exact errro message is below.

`main.cpp:5:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ASAN_POISON_MEMORY_REGION' ASAN_POISON_MEMORY_REGION(data+5, sizeof(int)*5);`
and 
`main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'sanitizer/asan_interface.h' file not found #include <sanitizer/asan_interface.h>`

Comment: @yugr I'm using clang version 5.0.1.

Comment: I suspect this is specific to old versions of clang (pre-7).

Answer (score 2):

This is the questioner's own answer.

Adding #include <sanitizer/asan_interface.h> is needed for using ASAN_POISON_MEMORY_REGION.
You can include it by installing compiler-rt.

Answer (score 1):

It's looks like your clang++ doesn't contain address sanitizer. Try to use another compiler or check if [compiler-rt](https://compiler-rt.llvm.org/) exist in your current compiler.

Also maybe you need to update your LDFLAGS with clang++ paths.